# How to Check for Unique Data in Django Form?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, formset

I'm following the examples posted on [Django Formset Documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/) regarding custom formset validation with a slight modification.  I found a flaw in the example but unsure how to fix it.  Is there a way to check for uniqueness in the data if the 1 of 3 input field is not completely filled out?  Apparently, empty form are recorded as "None" which forces me to at least fill out 2/3 sets of input field (firstname/lastname); otherwise, it will register as duplicates.  To illustrate what I mean:

forms.py

```
class UserInfo (forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20, required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20, required = False)


class BaseUserInfoFormSet (BaseFormSet):

    def clean (self):
        if any (self.errors):
            return

        firstnames = []
        lastnames = []
        errors = []

        for form in self.forms:
            firstname = form.cleaned_data.get ('first_name')
            lastname = form.cleaned_data.get ('last_name')

            if ((firstname in firstnames) or (lastname in lastnames)) and len (errors) < 2:
                errors.append ('First and/or last name must be unique')
            if ((firstname == '') or (lastname == '')) and len (errors) < 2:
                errors.append ('First and/or last name cannot be blanked')

            firstnames.append (firstname)
            lastnames.append (lastname)
            print ('First Name List: ', firstnames)
            print ('Last Name List: ', lastnames)

        if errors:
            raise forms.ValidationError (errors)

        return self.cleaned_data
```

With only one set of firstname/lastname filled out, here's the result from the console.

```
First Name List:  ['John']
Last Name List:  ['Doe']

First Name List:  ['John', None]
Last Name List:  ['Doe', None]

First Name List:  ['John', None, None]
Last Name List:  ['Doe', None, None]
```

Because there are duplicate "None", it triggered an error:

```
errors.append ('First and/or last name must be unique')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it by adding an 'if' statement to check for None.

```
if (firstname or lastname) is not None:
    firstnames.append (firstname)
    lastnames.append (lastname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you do not need blank values, so why not make the fields required. This will remove the None issue altogether, as all the fields would then be required.

Else, you could only add the values to the list if they are not empty

```
if firstname: 
    firstnames.append(firstname)
if lastname: 
    lastnames.append(lastname)
```

Comment: I had that thoughts but as you can see, a user is required to fill out all 8, 20, 100 fields which make it unpractical if they only have one set of entry to enter.  To solve that, I've set the first/last name input field in the html form to "required."